# Having trouble with file path in BlueJ

Tags: java

Im trying to create an application that reads names from an input file and writes the number of duplicate names on an output file. Heres my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class GenerateDuplicateBookTitle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // declare and intialize path where the input file is stored
    String filePath = "C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Desktop/JavaProgram";
    
    // intialize input file name and output file name
    String inputFile = "bookTitles.inp";
    String ouputFile = "duplicateTitles.inp";
    
    // create HashSet which does not store duplicate values
    HashSet<String> bookTitles = new HashSet<>();
    
    
    // create arrayList which stores only duplicate bok titles
    ArrayList<String> duplicateBookTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    // now read the book titles from the bookTitles.inp
    try{
        
        // create an object Of fileReader class with the specified filename with the path
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath+inputFile);
        
        // create an object of BufferedReader class for reading line from inp file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
        String getLine = "";
        
        System.out.println("-------------- Fetch data from the file ---------------\n");
        while((getLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            
            // add book title to the bookTitles arrayList
            if(!bookTitles.contains(getLine)){
                
                // diplay to the console
                System.out.println(getLine+" read successfully from "+filePath+inputFile);
            
                // add to the hash set
                bookTitles.add(getLine);
                
            }else{
                
                
                duplicateBookTitles.add(getLine);
            }
                
        }
        
        // display duplicate book title into the console
        System.out.print("Duplicate book titles fetched from "+filePath+inputFile+" : ");
        System.out.println(duplicateBookTitles.toString());
        
        // now store it into the "duplicateTitles.txt" file
        
        // create an object of FIleWriter class for writing data into the txt file
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter(filePath+ouputFile);
        
        System.out.println("\n------------ Write Duplicate BookTitles ----------------\n");
        
        // now get each element from the duplicateBookTitles arrayList
        for(String duplicateBookTitle : duplicateBookTitles){
            
            // write into the "duplicateTitles.txt" file
            write.write(duplicateBookTitle+"\n");
            
            // print on console
            System.out.println(duplicateBookTitle+" write succssfully into the 
            "+filePath+ouputFile);
        }
        
        // close the writer
        write.close();
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        
        
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        
        System.out.println("FILE '"+inputFile+"' IS NOT FOUND in "+filePath);
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    
    
}
```

I keep getting an error message that the input file can't be found even though I am typing in the exact address of the file. The file name and format are correct and its in the same folder as the BlueJ program. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the directory path and the filename without the `"/"`. Change `FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath+inputFile);` to:

```java
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath + "/" + inputFile);
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```java
FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(filePath, inputFile));
```

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work

Comment: Are you doing the same for the output file too? If still doesn't work, then try `File f = new File(filePath, inputFile)` and then print `f.getAbsolutePath()`, and check whether it exists or not.